# Правильно реализовать условие в матлабе

Tags: matlab

По отдельности все работает, но при соединение в одно условие, ломается.

```
M = [9,5,7.3,NaN,-5; inf,41,23,NaN,3.32; 17,4,-15,inf,6;3,10,64.4,42,NaN]
M(isnan(M))=0
M(~isfinite(M))=0
M(M<0)=0
M(rem(M,2)==0)=0
M(fix(M)~=M)=0
M(isprime(M)==0)=0
```

Мой вариант записи условия.Нужно отсортировать массив, оставив только простые числа

```
M(isnan(M)|~isfinite(M)|isprime((rem(M,2)==0)==0) | isprime ((fix(M)~=M)==0))=0
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не получится сделать в одну строку, функция isprime работает только с натуральным аргументом.